# Biztalk looping XML to flat file

Tags: xml, csv, biztalk

I have an input record that looks like this:

```
<employee>
    <empid>1234</empid>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    ...
    <benefit>
         <plan_name>HSA</plan_name>
         <effective_date>01-01-2015</effective_date>
    </benefit>
</employee>
```

I need to take this to a csv file. So far so good. Now there is a problem in that some of the employees have multiple benefits.

```
<employee>
    <empid>1234</empid>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    ...
    <benefit>
         <plan_name>HSA</plan_name>
         <effective_date>01-01-2015</effective_date>
    </benefit>
    <benefit>
         <plan_name>Limited FSA</plan_name>
         <effective_date>01-01-2015</effective_date>
    </benefit>
</employee>
```

In this situation, the resulting CSV file needs to have a new line for the second benefit. All the fields that are not benefits will be repeated on this line. I tried a looping functoid going from the the benefit node in the source to the entire record of the destination (as a guy at work who does most of our BizTalk suggested), but it isn't repeating the line for those in the test file that have multiple benefits. I just get one line for each employee.

What I need:

```
1234,John Smith,...HSA,01-01-2015
1234,John Smith,...Limited FSA,01-01-2015
```

What I get:

```
1234,John Smith,...HSA,01-01-2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty easy, I've done it a number of times.

Start by linking `<benefit>` to `<theCSVRowWlement>` with a Looping Functoid.

That will cause the Mapper to generate a for-each around `<benefit>` containing the entire CSV record.

Comment: I have no idea why it worked this time when I did it before and got only 1 record back each time. Thank you!